# How to split a stringstream into a vector with 2 kinds of delimiters (space and quotes)

Tags: c++

Can anyone help with with regards to splitting a string stream into a vector?

I have an earlier implementation of this that looks like:

```
int main()
{
    string console_cmd;
    std::vector<string> cmdList;

    cout << ">> ";
    getline(cin, console_cmd);

    istringstream iss(console_cmd);

    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
        istream_iterator<string>(),
        back_inserter(cmdList));

    return 0;
}
```

My inputs mostly llok like this

```
>> check -file /folder/filename.txt
```

So the vector cmdList would contain

```
cmdList[0] = check
cmdList[1] = -file
cmdList[2] = /folder/filename.txt
```

Later on, I had problems with the directory, particularly directories with spaces. Example:

```
>> check -file /folder name/filename.txt
```

The output of this becomes like this:

```
cmdList[0] = check
cmdList[1] = -file
cmdList[2] = /folder
cmdList[3] = name/filename.txt
```

I want it to look like this:

```
cmdList[0] = check
cmdList[1] = -file
cmdList[2] = /folder name/filename.txt
```

I was thinking of using delimiters but I am not sure how to implement this.

**EDIT: Adding how I will use the delimiters**

```
>> check -file "/folder name/filename.txt"
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you require the user to quote the filename or use an escapce sequence if it contains spaces it could be done with some parsing. Quoting:
`check -file "/folder name/filename.txt"` Escape seq: `check -file /folder\ name/filename.txt` but it's tricky sometimes. Especially if the quoting char may be a part of the filename too.

Comment: Will you always use the *absolute path* beginning with `'/'`? If so, you can use `console_cmd.find()` (or `.find_first_of()`) member functions to locate the first `'/'` marking the beginning of the filename.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes quite tricky for me.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin with regards to the abl=olute path, not always. Sometimes, it can start with "C:/user/folder name/...". So i thought about using double quotes (") as delimiters. Although, I am not n=sure how to implement this.

Comment: Using `getline()` you will preserve the double-quotes in your input. So you can use `console_cmd.find()` or `console_cmd.find_first_of()` to get the index for the first double-quote and then use `.find_lasr_of()` to find the last one and extract the substring in between. See: [std::basic_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) You can then extract what comes before the first double-quote and make a `stringstream` and parse the cmd and option from that.

Comment: You can also use `std::regex`, see [Regular expressions library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) specifically [std::regex_token_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) for an example of extracting between delimiters.

Comment: it's a bad idea to tokenize strings this way. It won't work for escaped strings like `check -file "/special \"folder name\"/filename.txt"`